# How to find a given value appears in how many tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables.

Given a *discount* value, I want to find if that *discount* value appears in how many tables (out of 5). Is it in all 5 tables? or just in 2 tables etc.

E.g: lets say 12% discount. I want to check if 12% exists in how many tables (out of 5 tables)

Note: *discount* value appears only one time in a given table (unique discounts)

Can someone please help me :)

**Tables**

```
table1(userid,discount)  
table2(userid,discount)    
table3(userid,discount)    
table4(userid,discount)    
table5(userid,discount)
```

Comment: Those are 5 different tables holding the same information or are they tuples?

Comment: in what scenario you have designed your db like that?

Comment: In a very bizarre scenario

Comment: This is like discounts given for 5 different shops :)

Comment: have u figured......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numOfDiscounts
FROM (
   SELECT discount 
   FROM table1
   WHERE discount = 12

   UNION ALL

   SELECT discount 
   FROM table2
   WHERE discount = 12

   UNION ALL

   SELECT discount 
   FROM table3
   WHERE discount = 12
   UNION ALL

   SELECT discount 
   FROM table4
   WHERE discount = 12

   UNION ALL

   SELECT discount 
   FROM table5
   WHERE discount = 12) AS t
```

The above query gives the number of tables containing a row with `discount = 12`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f978bc/2)

Alternatively, you can use:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE discount = 12),0) + 
       COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE discount = 12),0) + 
       COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE discount = 12),0) + 
       COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table4 WHERE discount = 12),0) + 
       COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table5 WHERE discount = 12),0) AS numOfDiscounts
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f978bc/3)

or:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN discount=12 THEN 1 END) FROM table1) + 
       (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN discount=12 THEN 1 END) FROM table2) + 
       (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN discount=12 THEN 1 END) FROM table3) + 
       (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN discount=12 THEN 1 END) FROM table4) + 
       (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN discount=12 THEN 1 END) FROM table5) AS numOfDiscounts
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc8ab/1)

Answer (score 3):

only option you can use is left join with all the tables that will give you the table where your data resides

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
 with CTE(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
 AS
 ((select CASE when count(1) >0 then 1 else 0 end 
from table1
where discount=@discount)  ,
(select CASE when count(1) >0 then 1 else 0 end 
from table2
where discount=@discount),
(select CASE when count(1) >0 then 1 else 0 end 
from table3
where discount=@discount),
(select CASE when count(1) >0 then 1 else 0 end 
from table4
where discount=@discount),
(select CASE when count(1) >0 then 1 else 0 end 
from table5
where discount=@discount)) 

select col1+col2+col3+col4+col5 from CTE
```